# How to avoid "NSInternalInconsistencyException" in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am sorting an mutable array. For sorting I use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pubDate" ascending:NO]; 
[recent sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];  
recent1 = [recent sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
[descriptor release];
```

I am getting this error:

> `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

The line

```
recent1 = [recent sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
```

show warnings

- "passing argument 1 of 'sortedarrayusingdescritors' from distinct objective c type " and
- "assignment from distinct objective c type"

In my code, both `recent` and `recent1` are `NSMutable` arrays. Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recent1 = [recent sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
```

must be:

```
recent1 = [recent sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];
```

Though I have no idea why you would want to sort an array that you already sorted with the same sort descriptors on the line directly above.